# Exposing API through TCP layer is secure than Appliaction(Http)?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, sockets, nettcpbinding

I have a doubt of exposing my API either through TCP (i.e. through socket) or through Http protocol (A REST service).

I want that communication to happen inside a network. As I am not going to expose the port( where I am going to deploy the service), I think exposing the API through Http or TCP(socket) does not matter.

I want to secure my APIs till the system has a public IP in near future.

So which one I should prefer exposing through TCP or HTTP ?

Comment: Since HTTP uses TCP port 80, your solutions are functionally identical. You will require a public port to the outside **or** a VPN to the internal network.

Comment: I think this is down to what API you want to have between your services and what you prefer. Http/REST has some benefits and it has sort of become an industry standard these days. You will find a lot of framework supporting this. If you are planning to expose your APIs to third parties at some point, REST could be the way to go. 

Having a custom API over TCP with fixed sockets would probably be faster and you will have full control over the payload and can do optimisations as you like.